# How can I disable/enable a target attribute for the static initialization block in clang

Tags: c++, clang, pragma

I had an avx file that ended up with a static initialization block that contained avx code but shouldn't. In attempting to resolve the issue I tried marking the region with a pragma attribute:
https://godbolt.org/z/xbGvG4noh

But the resulting initialization block still has avx code.

The reverse problem also shows up, but is obviously significantly less concerning:
https://godbolt.org/z/r5P7dWP18

I tried adjusting the match rules as listed here:
[Specifying attributes for multiple declarations](https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.1/tools/clang/docs/LanguageExtensions.html?highlight=apply_to#specifying-an-attribute-for-multiple-declarations-pragma-clang-attribute)
but none of the other match rules seem to hit this block either.

Besides command line arguments, is there any way to apply attributes to the static initialization block?